# Event log message file issue

Tags: .net, message, event-log

One of the applications I work on has been spitting out ugly event log messages that have our message but also the wonderful message such as below:

```
The description for Event ID 103 from source MyCustomSource cannot be found. Either  the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

My event log message that is redacted.

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

So I went about my way creating an event log message file for this source, sounds pretty simple right?

```
;// Header
MessageIdTypedef=DWORD

LanguageNames=(
    English=0x409:MSG00409
)

;// Categories
MessageId=0x1
SymbolicName=MYAPP_CATEGORY_GENERAL
Language=English
MyApp General
.

;// Messages
MessageId=0x103
SymbolicName=API_ERROR
Severity=Error
Language=English
An error occurred in the API. Message: %1
.
```

I then compile this file as normal:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\mc.exe" -u MyAppMessages.mc"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\rc.exe" -r MyAppMessages.rc"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe" -dll -noentry -out:MyAppMessages.dll MyAppMessages.res /MACHINE:x86
```

I now have the compiled MyAppMessages.dll. I now add the required registry entries:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\MyApp\MyApp
CategoryCount    REG_DWORD    1
CategoryMessageFile REG_EXPAND_SZ <path to MyAppMessages.dll>
EventMessageFile REG_EXPAND_SZ <path to MyAppMessages.dll>
```

The problem is, I'm still getting the same message as at the beginning, only the Task Category is now loading the correct value from the message file instead of the default value (1) that was loading previously.

This is the XML of the event data:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="MyApp" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="57344">103</EventID> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>1</Task> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-02-27T16:42:20.000000000Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>20759</EventRecordID> 
    <Channel>MyApp</Channel> 
    <Computer>Skycaller</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>My event log message that is redacted.</Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I'm no message file expert, but it is finding the category definition in the message file but not the event message. Does anyone have any insight as to why the message can't be found but the category is found in the same DLL?

Comment: EDIT: As further information, using Resource Hacker I am able to open the compiled resource file and it has all of the messages in it.

Comment: Compiling with SDK 7.1 instead of 7.0A also makes no difference, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, someone on the MSDN forums accidentally stumbled on the solution to this and shared it with me.

Simply take out any lines with `Severity=xxxxx` and `Facility=xxxxx` in the message file and the custom messages will show up once you recompile. `Facility` was not in my file but the other guy had that line in his and it wouldn't work for him without taking that line out too. No idea why those lines are in lots of the tutorials and the official MSDN documentation examples but there it is.

Hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You defined your MessageId values as hexidecimal so 0x103 converts to 259 decimal.  If you want your MessageId to be 103 decimal then use MessageId=0x67

Comment: I've tried MessageId values 103 (the most obvious), 0x103 (matches some of the documentation on MSDN) as well as 0x67 which is, as you state, the correct hex value of 103d. None of them get picked up by the event log. :( The categories work in either decimal or hex, so strange that the messages don't work!

Answer (score 0):

The EventId is a combination from the MessageId, Severity and Facility. I have read this from the following source:  "Any value specified must fit in 16 bits. For more details on how the message value is formed from the severity, facility, and message ID, see the diagram in Winerror.h." by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

That's why it is working if you take Severity and Facility out of the message file.

Answer (score 0):

The `dwEventId` argument that is passed to the Win32 [`ReportEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679(v=vs.85).aspx) call is not strictly the same as the `MessageId` in your message file; rather it should be constructed out of `Severity`, `Facility` and `MessageId` combined together; bitshifted and OR'd, as described by `winerror.h`.

Helpfully, the Message Compiler in addition to an RC and BIN file also spits out a header file that `#defines` the mapping from `SymbolicName` (if provided) to the correct `EventId` for each message. So you can just use those constants if you want to make use of `Severity` and `Facility` in your Windows Event Log messages.

Note that if you do specify a value for `Facility` or `Severity` for any message, then that value will be the assumed default by the Message Compiler for any subsequent messages that don't define `Facility` or `Severity`, until a message is reached which specifies a value for `Facility` or `Severity` which becomes the new default, etc, etc.